# How to detect if a word is present in a cell, within a string?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, copy-paste, vba

I have some code I'm working on where I need to detect if a cell has a particular word in it, and if it does, it inserts a particular string in the adjacent cell. However, I'm having issues doing the detection part of it! Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub searchandpaste()
    Dim stopvar As Variant
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim j As Variant
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim TestVal1 As Variant
    Dim TestVal2 As Variant

    i = 0
    j = 0

    Do While stopvar = 0
        i = i + 1
        MsgBox ("Row " & i)
        MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
        'If the first cell is empty, that means we've hit the end of the worksheet, and it stops the do-while loop
        TestVal1 = Cells(i, 1)
        If TestVal1 = 0 Then
            stopvar = 1
        Else
            TestVal2 = Cells(i, 6)
            If IsEmpty(TestVal2) = True Then
                MsgBox ("Detected Empty Cell in Column 6")
                j = 1
            ElseIf TestVal2 = "XXXX" Then
                'This means we have a place we need to insert a value
                MsgBox ("Detected XXXX in Column 6")
                'We know at this point that in Cells(6,i) we have a value we need to insert. Thus, we need to search Cells(7,i) for key text
                If IsNumeric(Cells(7, j).Find("CYLINDER")) Or IsNumeric(Cells(7, j).Find("CYLINDERS")) Or IsNumeric(Cells(7, j).Find("CYL")) = True Then
                    MsgBox ("Detected the string CYLINDER")
                    j = j + 1
                    MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Did not detect the string CYLINDER")
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'll cut out the important part, here.

```
'We know at this point that in Cells(6,i) we have a value we need to insert. Thus, we need to search Cells(7,i) for key text
If IsNumeric(Cells(7, j).Find("CYLINDER")) Or IsNumeric(Cells(7, j).Find("CYLINDERS")) Or IsNumeric(Cells(7, j).Find("CYL")) = True Then
    MsgBox ("Detected the string CYLINDER")
    j = j + 1
    MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
Else
    MsgBox ("Did not detect the string CYLINDER")
End If
```

My intention is that this would search the string in cell (i,7) for different variations of the word Cylinder, and if it finds one, it'll return TRUE or FALSE (false would be a NAN, which is caught by the IsNumeric and turned to a FALSE), and let me know it detected it. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

Can anybody pinpoint my error?

Is there a better way to search the string? Like, could I just search for "CYL" and have it say it detected any of those variations?

Comment: You should use the `InStr` method to do the comparison like this: `If InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYLINDER") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYLINDERS") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYL") > 0 Then`

Comment: Also, what happens when "Cyl", "cyl"? Why don't you turn the word to uppercase in your code to cover those scenarios -UCase()-? Or use Option Compare Text at the beginning of the module, I don't understand why to make 3 comparisons, if cell has "CYL" of course it would have CYLINDER and CYLINDERS on it.

Comment: Great, thank you Ralph. And you're correct Sgdva. @Ralph, if you submit that as a comment I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `InStr` function to do the comparison like this:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYLINDER") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYLINDERS") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYL") > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Detected the string CYLINDER")
        j = j + 1
        MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
Else
    MsgBox ("Did not detect the string CYLINDER")
End If
```

For more information on this function visit MSDN at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811%28v=office.15%29.aspx

To avoid different cases (as suggested by @Sgdva) you have several options:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYLINDER", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYLINDERS", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, Cells(7, j), "CYL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Detected the string CYLINDER")
        j = j + 1
        MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
Else
    MsgBox ("Did not detect the string CYLINDER")
End If
```

OR

```
If InStr(1, UCase(Cells(7, j)), "CYLINDER") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, UCase(Cells(7, j)), "CYLINDERS") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, UCase(Cells(7, j)), "CYL") > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Detected the string CYLINDER")
        j = j + 1
        MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
Else
    MsgBox ("Did not detect the string CYLINDER")
End If
```

OR

Use the `Option Compare Text` at the top of your module and as pointed out here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278697.aspx

At the same time, you might want to consider inserting the line:

```
Option Explicit
```

(for good coding practice).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the `j` variable as it doesn't seem to have any relevance. Except I seem to have identified an error in your code and the answer provided by Ralph. `Cells(7, j)` should rather be `Cells(i, 7)`. Full code would be:

```
Sub searchandpaste()
    Dim stopvar As Variant
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim j As Variant
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim TestVal1 As Variant
    Dim TestVal2 As Variant

    i = 0
    j = 0

    Do While stopvar = 0
        i = i + 1
        MsgBox ("Row " & i)
        MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
        'If the first cell is empty, that means we've hit the end of the worksheet, and it stops the do-while loop
        TestVal1 = Cells(i, 1)
        If TestVal1 = 0 Then
            stopvar = 1
        Else
            TestVal2 = Cells(i, 6)
            If IsEmpty(TestVal2) = True Then
                MsgBox ("Detected Empty Cell in Column 6")
                j = 1
            ElseIf TestVal2 = "XXXX" Then
                'This means we have a place we need to insert a value
                MsgBox ("Detected XXXX in Column 6")
                'We know at this point that in Cells(6,i) we have a value we need to insert. Thus, we need to search Cells(7,i) for key text
                If InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 7)), "cyl") > 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Detected the string CYLINDER")
                    j = j + 1
                    MsgBox ("j equals " & j)
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Did not detect the string CYLINDER")
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: j is how I'm tracking something else. It's not super relevant to the current code. Thank you for putting it together!